# sys.stdin.readline() with if else (Python)

Tags: python

I am new at Python and need a little help. 
I am trying to use the next command in order to get user input from screen:
sys.stdin.readline()

All is fine when I want to print something but when I am trying to combine an if else statement it seems that the user input is ignoring the case sensitive string that I wrote in the if == and it always return the else even when I writing the input 'Sam'

I want to make a simple task like this one:

```
print("What is your name ?")

name = sys.stdin.readline()

print("Hello", name)

if name == 'Sam' :
    print ('You are in our group')
else :
    print('You are not in our group')
```

What should I do in the sys.stdin.readline() will acknowledge the if == argument ?

Thank you for you Help

Comment: You can use the raw_input() function instead of sys.stdin.readline(), as it ignores the end of line character ('\n')

Comment: @Jalo, looks like they're using python3 so it would be `input('Prompt: ')`.

Comment: Alright @Holloway, I did not notice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line will include the end of line character `'\n'` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)). So it's never equal to `'Sam'` (except possibly at the end of the file).

Maybe use `name = name.strip()` to remove it and any extra whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks @RemcoGerlich !
Now it's recognize Sam :)

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the main post:

I used sys.stdin.readline() and input() in the same code. Worked both times. Below are the codes:

```
import sys
print('how much was your meal')
price = int(input())
print('how much would you like to tip in percentage')
tip = int(input())
tipamount = price * (tip/100)
print('your tip amount is %s' %tipamount + 'dollars')
```

Second code:

```
#import sys
#price = int(sys.stdin.readline())
#print('how much would you like to tip in percentage')
#tip = int(sys.stdin.readline())
#tipamount = price * (tip/100)
#print('your tip amount is %s' %tipamount + 'dollars')
```

But when I used sys.stdin.readline in the following code, it didn't work. Instead input() worked. Could someone please explain why sys.stdin.readline worked in the first code but not in this one?

```
import sys
print('are you looking to study digital media in australia?')
answer = str(sys.stdin.read())
if answer == 'yes':
print('Deakin University has one of the best Digital Science Program!')
```